# Tinder-like navigation in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

i'm trying to use [this](https://github.com/davidseek/SLPagingViewSwift-Swift-3-Tinder-Twitter) framework that provides a navigation bar like Tinder's (Swift 3).

my goal is to use this in a transperant way - meaning - to embed it and have 3 independent view controllers on storyboard, with their VC.swift files and use segues.

[Here](https://github.com/davidseek/TinderTest) is a working test project with Tinder style and 3 ViewControllers from Storyboard.

before using it in my project i wanted to test it so i updated this project.

As i saw, nav is the UINavigationController that have the 3 VC's and switching between them. i wanted to see him on the storyboard.

so insted of:

```
var nav: UINavigationController?
```

i created a UINavigationController on the UI builder and UINavigationController class called MainNavigationController.

```
var nav: MainNavigationController?
nav = mainStb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainNavigationController") as? MainNavigationController
```

i also added a simple initial view controller to storyboard, from this VC i segue (using a button) to the MainNavigationController:

```
@IBAction func buttonSegue(_ sender: Any) {
        setNav()

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: nil)
    }

func setNav() {


    //// implement my logic (if logged in go to... if not go to...)

    instantiateControllers()
    setItems()

    let items = [UIImageView(image: chat),
                 UIImageView(image: gear),
                 UIImageView(image: profile)]

    let controllers = [oneVC!,
                       twoVC!,
                       threeVC!] as [UIViewController]

    controller = SLPagingViewSwift(items: items, controllers: controllers, showPageControl: false)

    setupController()


    nav = MainNavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = nav
    appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

it all works so far. **BUT**:

The only problem i currently have is that i don't have control on the segues. in the 3 view controllers i added

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
```

but it is never hitting this method. i need it to pass data between view controllers. how can it be done?

Additionally, how would you implement a segue from one view controller to another by tapping an element (like a button)? if i set a regular segue, using a button, from one VC to another - it shows the target VC without the navigation bar

i uploaded my current implementation [here](https://github.com/eyalby/TinderTest-master).

any help will be appricieated.
thanks.

Comment: * thanks to @DavidSeek for the code in the swift 3 version of the SLPagingView and the sample project with VC's as well.

Comment: The `performSegueWithIdentifier` in your button method isn't doing anything for you since you have already replaced the root view controller in `setNav` and your views are now "outside" the storyboard environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. I have downloaded your project, because your explanation wasn't really helpful..

First of all: If you have a storyboard with nothing but blank screens, color them for other coders to be able to tell faster what's going on.

[image]

Your segue from the yellow `VC` to the `UINavigationController` is triggered, but not used because you instantiate the `UINavigationController` programatically.

```
// Sets the root
func setNav() {
    // here        
    nav = MainNavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = nav
    appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Your segue from the green VC to the blue VC doesn't make any sense because there is no segue. Those controllers are embedded into the same controller. 
You are setting up the `perform(forSegue` function, but you are never calling it. You only use `perform(forSegue` if there is a segue. But that is not the case.

Setting the button without the `setNav()` function:

```
@IBAction func buttonSegue(_ sender: Any) {
    //setNav()
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: nil)
}
```

Results in the blue `VC` as single `VC`.

[image]

Same function without the segue, results in the same logic, as with the segue. Because as said, you set up everything programatically anyways:

```
@IBAction func buttonSegue(_ sender: Any) {
    setNav()
    //self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: nil)
}
```

[image]

Since you have instantiated the `VCs` globally, you are able to get/set `VCs` values globally...

```
class OneVC: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func passData(_ sender: Any) {
        let oneVCString = "This String is passed from OneVC"
        twoVC?.theLabel.text = oneVCString
    }
}
```

And the outcome:

[image]

[Here is this on Github](https://github.com/davidseek/TinderTest-master) as a fork of your project. Also I have deleted your code from the `AppDelegate`. Wasn't useful and called anyways. You did the same in the Interface Builder already.

Last but not least a comment from me: Clean up your code! Other users might have a different opinion on that, but this is not how I want to work with other coders:

```
import UIKit

class TwoVC: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        print("from two to...")
        print(segue.identifier!)
    }
    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Remove all the unnecessary comments.

Comment: Thanks @DavidSeek, it is all clear now. i just added the segue-like line: "controller.setCurrentIndex(1, animated: false)"   to the end of func passData. and that is exactly what i needed to demonstrate to myself and understand. i'm sorry for the mass and the coding poor standards. I still consider my self as very new to swift. i'm happy to receive your general comments and tips. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It wasn't meant to offend or pull you back. I was just giving you (in my understanding) helpful tips. Since the question is answered then, please don't forget to accept and if helpful, upvote.

Comment: They were helpful, As i said, @DavidSeek your tips are always welcome. I created another (important) question, would love if you take a look. thanks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40428075/segue-from-a-slpagingviewswift-vc-and-dismiss-the-destination-vc-to-return

Comment: Hi @DavidSeek or other viewers. i posted a related question with a sample project with the issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40428075/segue-from-a-slpagingviewswift-vc-and-dismiss-the-destination-vc-to-return i can't find how to implemented the solutions i found in my context (SLPagingView). i would appreciate it a lot if someone can take a look and help, Thanks!